# How to export .pdf from numbers without background

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, background-removal

I'm looking for a way to export a spread I made in Apple's Numbers program to a .pdf without adding a background. Is it possible to export only the cells?

I'll be importing them into InDesign so it can't be a .csv or .xlsx document.

Since I'll have to do over 200 of them, it would be awesome if someone has a solution to this so the aligning can be automatic.

Comment: Hi Marjolein, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: just copy the cells you want and past it into indesign.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure if there's a way to export a PDF from Numbers without keep all document information (background included)... My guess is that there is not.

However, if you just need the numerical data from the Numbers doc, why not save it as an .xlsx file? You definitely CAN import that doc type into InDesign, the same way you'd import/place a photo (Cmd-D; choose the .xlsx file).

Then if you choose, you can set up a new table in InDesign with the necessary number of rows & columns, and copy/paste the data into the new table. The data should remain in their respective cells when you paste it into the new table.